# Why does the current intensity decrease when I connect two voltage sources in series?

Tags: voltage-divider, multimeter, current-divider

I actually connected lemons with batteries and I found that the voltage of lemon and the battery (i.e. the bottom left circuit) is **3.8V** while the current intensity in the top left circuit is **0.1mA**!

The question is why the current intensity in the top left circuit is **0.1mA** while the current intensity in the top center circuit is **1.56mA** and the current intensity in the top right circuit is **0.013mA**?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOPKB7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Besides that lemons are neither accurate nor reliable nor ideal voltage sources, we have no idea what resistances are involved, nor how the measurement equipment looks like (e.g. burden voltage etc.)

Comment: I'd guess that Lemon2 is "bad" and because it's in series with Lemon1 in your top-left circuit, it is causing the current to be limited in the circuit. Try replacing Lemon2 with a freshly charged lemon...

Comment: Yes it is the reason, because of its internal resistance which is very large. @brhans

Comment: Anode and cathode surface are is a big deal.

Comment: You mean lemon 2 is ... a lemon?

Comment: LSR! Lemon Series Resistance!

Comment: Exactly. Lemon refers to actual lemons. @BrianDrummond

Comment: Internal resistance of the lemon battery is really high

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mainly because the lemon is far from being an "ideal" voltage source — it has a considerable amount of internal resistance, which limits the current that can pass through it.